# Send extra items to next column CSS

Tags: css

[image]

I am trying to achieve the following, I need to send the extra item to the next column if there are more contents. Also, the width of the parent should reduce/extend based on that. I am banging my head since 2 hours, any help is appreciated. 
I am ok with the flexbox if we can achieve with that.

```css
.card-body {
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-body">
  <ul>
    <li>
      Testing
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing 1
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing 2
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing 3
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It wont happen as you are using Flex; Column

Comment: @ThanveerShah this is exactly the purpose of using column

Answer (score 2):

You need to restrict the height of the ul or this one will simply overflow the parent container:

```css
.card-body {
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-height:100%;
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-body">
  <ul>
    <li>
      Testing
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing 1
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing 2
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing 3
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect Answer.

Answer (score 1):

simply applying column-count more then 2 and max-height working

```css
 .card-body {
      height: 200px;
      border: 1px solid;
      padding: 10px;
    }

    ul {
       -moz-column-count: 3;
        -webkit-column-count: 3;
        column-count: 3;
        width: 30em;
        max-height:90%;

    }
```

```html
<div class="card-body">
  <ul>
    <li>
      Testing
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing 1
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing 2
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing 3
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing 1
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing 2
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing 3
    </li>
    
    <li>
      Testing 1
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing 2
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing 3
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing 1
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing 2
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing 3
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing 1
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing 2
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing 3
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing 1
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing 2
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing 3
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing 1
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing 2
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing 3
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing 1
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing 2
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing 3
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Read the question again, He wants only the overflow items to go the next line once it hits the bottom.

Comment: You are still doing the same thing here. When you give column-count, You are telling the elements to divide in 3 columns, He wants the natural flow of columns accordingly ,He doesn't want to specify the column count manually

Comment: Haha yeah exactly

Comment: Yes it will, But use Display:flex, flex-direction:column ;flex-wrap:wrap instead of your code.

Comment: we can even manipulate spacing between column by increasing or decreasing column-count

Comment: Nop, I don't think so , Unless you use flex,Because when you use columns, You are specifying it directly .

Comment: The column space can be decreased by changing the width of the container.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to set `height` for `ul` elements, also to make it look more clean I've added `box-sizing` rule:

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.card-body {
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  height:100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-body">
  <ul>
    <li>
      Testing
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing 1
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing 2
    </li>
    <li>
      Testing 3
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify a max-height or height in your ul element, so that it knows when to stop growing vertically.